# Speed up copy and paste in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fix up a 1600 line database by copying and pasting but the code below is slow. Any ideas on how I may speed this up?

```
Sub copy()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = Sheets("UK File Cash Mod")

    For i = 2 To 1600
        If ws.Cells(i, 1) Like "384*" And Cells(i + 1, 1) = "" Then
            ws.Cells(i, 1).copy
            If ws.Cells(i + 1, 3) <> "" Then
                ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).PasteSpecial
                ws.Cells(i, 2).copy
                ws.Cells(i + 1, 2).PasteSpecial
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Use variant arrays and iterate those.  Limit the number of times vba refers to the worksheet.

Comment: You shouldn't use copy and paste it is resource intensive. do ```ws.cells(i + 1, 1).value = ws.cells(i, 1).value```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed every Copy-Paste by a simple `Destination.Value=Source.Value`, so you get this:

```
Sub copy()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim i As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set ws = Sheets("UK File Cash Mod")

  For i = 2 To 1600
    If ws.Cells(i, 1) Like "384*" And Cells(i + 1, 1) = "" Then
      If ws.Cells(i + 1, 3) <> "" Then
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
      End If
    Else
    End If
  Next i
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```